# Shield UI: Dragging to Create Group

Tags: javascript, grid, grouping, shieldui

I'm a designer who uses JavaScript / jQuery mainly for prototyping.  I'm currently evaluating the Shield UI library for a project, and am mainly interested in exploring the grid capabilities.  I've only been exploring the library for the last several hours, but have hit a stumbling block with enabling draggable grouping.  I followed the example on the product website ([http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-grouping/grouping)](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-grouping/grouping), and it works perfectly ONLY if I define a group in my data source.  I can then delete this initial group, and drag any of the column headers to the drop region to create groups.  However, if I don't have an initial group defined as part of my data source, the grouping drop region is present, but doesn't create a group when a column is dropped.

I tried adding an ungroup event after initially creating the grid, but that didn't solve the problem.  Is it possible to drag-and-drop group creation without defining an initial group?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [ungroup()](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/ungroup) method to remove the groups right after the Grid has been rendered and data loaded.